# Android action bar search view disable auto suggestions

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am using search view in action bar . My search is working perfectly in application. But just one problem. When ever i type a word. I see some device specific search suggestions pop up appear below my search view. I don't want these suggestions. I don't want any suggestions at all. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had same problem that was solved this way:
if you are using

```
searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();
```

than just delete this line it will work fine..